# Javascript Fruit-machine, how to display a winning message?

Tags: javascript

Im creating a basic fruit machine however I'm stuck when it comes to making a function to display and "Winner" or "Loser try again" message when all images are the same! (I know the images won't show but on here but it all works apart from a winner feature, click the bottom image to spin the machine):

```js
const images = ["apple.jpg", "bananas.jpg", "cherries.jpg", "lemon.jpg", "pineapple.jpg", "plum.jpg"];

var count;
const speed = 370;

function beginShow() {
  count = 20; // show 20 images
  nextImage();
}

function nextImage() {
  changeImage("pic1");
  changeImage("pic2");
  changeImage("pic3");

  count = count - 1; // count down
  if (count > 0) // repeat unless we're at zero
  {
    tim = setTimeout("nextImage();", speed);
  }
}

function changeImage(imageId) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  document.getElementById(imageId).src = images[rand];
}

function leverDown() {
  document.getElementById("lever").src = "lever2.jpg";

}

function leverUp() {
  document.getElementById("lever").src = "lever1.jpg";
}

function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/base.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/labsheet.css">
  <title>77103 Session 1 : In at the Deep End</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Slot Machine</h1>
  <img id="pic1" src="apple.jpg" />
  <img id="pic2" src="apple.jpg" />
  <img id="pic3" src="apple.jpg" />
  <br>

  <img onclick="beginShow(); play(); jackpot();" onmousedown="leverDown()" onmouseup="leverUp()" src="lever1.jpg" id="lever" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="fruit.js"></script>
  <audio id="audio" src="handlespin.wav"></audio>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain an array which will contain the final results of a round:

```
var results = [];
function nextImage() {
   results[0] = changeImage("pic1");
   results[1] = changeImage("pic2");
   results[2] = changeImage("pic3");

   count = count - 1; // count down
   if (count > 0) // repeat unless we're at zero
   {
      tim = setTimeout("nextImage();", speed);
   }
}

function changeImage(imageId) {
   var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
   document.getElementById(imageId).src = images[rand];
   return images[rand];
}
```

Now, back in `beginShow()` function check if results in `results` are the same:

```
function beginShow() {
   count = 20; // show 20 images
   nextImage();
   checkResults();
}

function checkResults() {
   if (results[0] === results[1] && results[1] === results[2]) {
       document.getElementById('result').innerHtml = 'You win';
   } else {
       document.getElementById('result').innerHtml = 'You lost!Try again';
   }
}
```

In your html just add an element with id `result`.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1G4JPT4B5hlhRBtLlSnu?p=preview) is a working plunker of what I am suggesting.